# json_decode() throws "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" though it is an object

Tags: php, json

This is my code:

```
$upload = json_decode($upload);
if( $upload->error ){...
```

this is $upload:

```
var_dump($upload);
object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
["error"]=> bool(false)
["status"]=> string(53) "..."
}

print_r($upload);
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => 
    [status] => ...
)
```

Why does if($upload->error) throw a notice even though it seems to be an object? Is it something about error being a boolean?

Comment: when you say "this is $upload:", you do mean upload _after_ you ran it through json_decode, or _before_? json_decode should take in a string (containing data in JSON format) and output an object. If that's what you've done, then your code should work. Perhaps you've misunderstood the purpose of that function? The message is nothing to do with error being a boolean or not. The "non-object" it's referring to is the $upload variable itself.

Comment: Is your `var_dump($upload)` **before** or **after** `$upload = json_decode($upload)`? How about making it clearer with `$decodedUpload = json_decode($upload);`?

Comment: Its after. $upload gets its value by a function that returns an json-string with json_encode().

Comment: btw: I'd like to improve my "question-asking-skills". As this one got downvoted, I have to ask: what's wrong about it?

Comment: See https://eval.in/869118 - your code seems to work, assuming an valid initial value for $upload. So either the above is not your real code, or your input JSON string is invalid (although if it really does actually produce the object you dumped, it's hard to see how that could be), or you've otherwise got your wires crossed somehow.

Comment: P.S. I'm intrigued by "$upload gets its value by a function that returns an json-string with json_encode()". Why are you encoding to JSON and then immediately un-encoding again? There's no need to do that within a single PHP program. The only reason really to encode to JSON is to transmit data to the browser, or perhaps to use as a storage format. Functions within the program can just pass objects to each other directly.

Comment: @ADyson Mh. You gave me something to think about. It's a habit of mine. I think because I constantly log some things in a database and/or use in JS, it just sort of "developed". Actually never thought about wether its wise to do. :D

Comment: Sounds like maybe you need to split your functions up in a more granular way, so you've got one endpoint which outputs the object as JSON, for the purpose of logging/output to browser, and a back-end function which ouputs the actual PHP object. The JSON endpoint then uses that back-end function to get the PHP object, and other parts of your PHP code can also call it directly to get the object un-encoded. Then you can re-use code more easily and avoid pointless encoding/un-encoding. That redundant processing could even potentially be the source of the problem you're experiencing

Comment: Your words sound useful. :) But I can't grasp it right away. Do you have a link or search suggestion for me, to read up on this? I'd really appreciate that. Thanks.

Comment: let's say you have a function "GetUser()" which returns a JSON string representing an application user. Useful for sending data to the browser. Not so useful if another PHP function wants to know about that user. So you can simply have two functions, "GetUserJSON()" and "GetUser()". GetUser() returns the actual PHP object and contains the logic to get the user data from the database (or whatever). "GetUserJSON()" simply calls GetUser() and then encodes the data to JSON before returning it. It does nothing else. Now you can call GetUser() from other PHP functions without any encoding problems..

Comment: ...but GetUserJSON() can still be used when you need to return JSON to the browser etc. Since it just calls GetUser in the background, the only functional difference is that it spits the same data out in a different format. It's just a conversion utility, effectively. That's a trivial example but it's a basic coding principle to split your code down into the smallest re-usable chunks you can manage, then you've got maximum flexibility in how you use it,  and minimum duplication of logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to facepalm myself real hard right now...

The above code - as you all pointed out - is correct.

The section I shared here, is part of a foreach-loop. The above mentioned function that sets $upload (because of some inner function workings) returns false on the very first iteration. (I assume) Nothing gets dumped or printed because $upload is false in this case.

Thats when the notice is thrown. The output from var_dump()/print_r() are from the second iteration.

In my test case the foreach had only two iterations, thats when I thought both notice and object belonged together...

Thanks to all of you anyway. Your comments showed me, I had to look elsewhere for the mistake.

Comment: In reference to your comment *'I'd like to improve my "question-asking-skills"'*, this answer contains information that you omitted from your question. There is not enough information given for anyone to provide an answer

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the feedback. I'll keep that in mind for future questions!

Answer (score -2):

Example #2 Accessing invalid object properties

Accessing elements within an object that contain characters not permitted under PHP's naming convention (e.g. the hyphen) can be accomplished by encapsulating the element name within braces and the apostrophe.

```
<?php

$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>
```

Comment: all of this is true, but how does it relate to the question? In the question, the property causing the problem, called "error", clearly doesn't violate the naming convention in this way.